# Macro that select tables from document and deleting specific rows

Tags: vba, ms-word

I try build macro that check every table in document and, if table contain cells with specific text, whole rows with this cells is deleting. I created sth like this below, but it works only for first table (it deletes rows which should be - this is ok) and throws Runtime error 5825 "Object has been deleted". What I should to macro work **for every table in document**, not only first one.

```
Sub test2()

    Dim t As Table

    For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables

    'ActiveDocument.Tables().Select
    Dim oRow As Row
    For Each oRow In t.Rows
            If oRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = "Wersja naprawy:" & vbCr & Chr(7) Then oRow.Delete
            If oRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = "Odnośne wersje:" & vbCr & Chr(7) Then oRow.Delete
        Next oRow
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code finds "Wersja naprawy:" it deletes the row, but then it tries to check that same row for "Odnośne wersje:". There is no row any more to check...

Try something like this:

```
Sub test2()

    Dim tbl As Table, txt, oRow As Row, arr

    arr = Array("Wersja naprawy:", "Odnośne wersje:")

    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each oRow In tbl.Rows
            For Each txt in arr
                If oRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = txt & vbCr & Chr(7) Then 
                    oRow.Delete
                    Exit For
                End If
             Next txt
        Next oRow
   Next tbl

End Sub
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you for comprehensive explantion of my mistake, its help me repair my other macros.